# Separate books from papers in bibliography of a paper

Tags: publications

Is there some automatic way to single out the books in bibliography of a paper in IEEE format?

For example, write some program or use some functionality of some editors to find out the books mentioned in [this paper](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~pift6080/H09/documents/papers/blind_source_tutorial.pdf) with 303 references in its bibliography?

Comment: Try brute force. Sit down by hand and examine each one. The last 100 seemed to be journal papers. I gave up then.

Comment: Write some code that starts with that paper on the ISI website and then crawls each reference link to determine the type. Probably ~ 20 to 50 lines of code in Python, would be a good exercise...

Comment: @mankoff: Thanks! (1) What is "ISI website"? (2) I am not familiar with Python and how to parse the text yet.

Comment: I agree with Dave Clarke; just do it.  It should take you about half a second per reference to identify the books, which is less than three minutes total.

Comment: ISI is the old name for Web Of Science.

Comment: [This](http://phdtools.blogspot.com/2011/07/making-bibtex-file-from-folder-of-pdf.html) seems to be what you are looking for. Essential some `bash` scripting. But as @JeffE says, it probably takes ~1second to scan through a reference so you won't be losing more than 5-6 minutes for a 300 reference list. Of course you can bash script the cr@p out of your pdf using some cunning `gs` and such but thats perhaps a mini-mini-project (which if you get to, please do share! )

Answer (score 3):

It's a partial answer, since it's not really automatic, but since this paper seems to have been done with Latex, you could probably ask the authors for their bibtex file, and then using a reference manager such as Bibdesk, Mendeley, Zotero, Papers, etc, you should be able to sort them by category, and therefore isolate all the books.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that you mentioned it was a partial answer. Still (1) Are authors always willing to give their bibtex files? I guess it may also not be realistic to me to contact everyone If I have such need for not just a paper. (2) What if there is just the pdf file available?

Comment: (1) I don't see why not, at least, I wouldn't mind sending it. You would also need the bbl or the aux of the paper, in order to know which paper are cited from their bib file. But yes, if you have to do it for many papers you want the references from, it might be a tedious to contact all the authors. (2) In that case, I don't know, but that doesn't mean there is no solution :)

Comment: Or "grep @book".